# Make menubar call method when it is clicked?

Tags: menu, javafx-2

I am wanting to add an empty `javafx.scene.control.Menu` to a MenuBar and have it call a method when it is clicked.

I have tried using `menu.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<Event>(){});` with no luck.

Here is what I am currently working with:

```
public MenuBar createMenuBar() {
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    Menu file = new Menu("File");

    Menu addAccountTab = new Menu("Add Tab");
    addAccountTab.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<Event>() {
        public void handle(Event e) {
            System.out.println("addAccountTab Menu clicked.");
        }
    });
    menuBar.getMenus().add(addAccount);
    return menuBar;
}
```

However, clicking the Menu does not call the onShowing event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the API suggests otherwise, the `onShowing` event doesn't get called when there are no MenuItems in the Menu or when they are all hidden.

I was able to solve the issue by using Menu's `hide()` method inside of the `onShown` event like this.

```
public MenuBar createMenuBar() {
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    Menu addAccount = MenuBuilder.create()
        .onShown(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            public void handle(Event e) {
                ((Menu)e.getSource()).hide();
                System.out.println("addAccount Clicked");
            }
        }).items(new MenuItem())
        .text("Add Account").build();
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(addAccount);

    return menuBar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Menu` needs to contain at least one `MenuItem` for the event to fire.

```
public class MenuApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu file = new Menu("File");

        Menu addAccountTab = new Menu("Add Tab");

        addAccountTab.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event e) {
                System.out.println("addAccountTab Menu clicked.");
            }
        });

        MenuItem NewMenuItem = new MenuItem("New");
        addAccountTab.getItems().add(NewMenuItem);

        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(file, addAccountTab);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The output I get is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I have found that using
`((Menu)e.getSource()).hide();` inside of Menu's `setOnShown()` event allows for clicking the Menu without having a ContextMenu appear.